# Scheduled Batch Apex class

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I need to write a `Scheduled Batch` Apex Class on two Objects `Case` and `Ticket__c`.

Note: Ticket__c Has a look up to the Case. So, a case can have multiple tickets but a ticket can only be associated to one case.

What the Scheduled Batch Class should do:

****** Run the batch apex at 2:00am every Morning

1. Get all the records of  a case whose status is Open, Breached and Escalated.
2. List all the tickets whose `Id = Case.Id`
3. Loop through to validate the `Ticket_c` status `(GLOBAL_Ticket_Status__c=Closed)`  // if not come out of the loop
4. Add the tickets id to case id and close the case after 7 days of Highest `LastModifiesDate` of a ticket associated to case i.e `Ticket__c (Status=close)` and Highster `Lastmodified > 7` close the case.

   ```
   global class CloseCaseBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{         

       global String query;

       global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
       {
           query = 'Select Id,  from Case WHERE Status = \'Open\' And ' +
                                          'Status = \'Escalated\' And' +
                                          'Status = \'Breached\''; //need to define query
           System.debug('checkcase---' + query);

           return Database.getQueryLocator(query);

      }

      global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope)
      {

         List<Case> scase= (List<Case>)scope; // ? scope is case
         System.debug('checkcase---' +scope);
         Set<ID> caseIDs = new Set<ID>();
         Map<ID,List<Ticket__c>> CaseID_TicketList = new Map<ID,List<Ticket__c>>();
         for(case cI : scase)
         {



           caseID.put(cI.id)
         }

         **// Need to setup caseID set ??**



   for (Ticket__c ticket : [Select ID, LastModifiedDate , GLOBAL_Ticket_Status__c,GLOBAL_Goal__c from Ticket__c where GLOBAL_Goal__c in :caseIDs]){


   /* List<Ticket__c> tkList = new List<Ticket__c>();
   if(CaseID_TicketList.containsKey(ticket.GLOBAL_Goal__c)){
       tkList = CaseID_TicketList.get(ticket.GLOBAL_Goal__c);

   else {
   tkList.add(ticket);
   }
   CaseID_TicketList.put(ticket.GLOBAL_Goal__c,tkList); */
           // Map case & ticket
       }

      Boolean allClosedTickets = true;
       // **Loop thru Map on Case for all associated tickets
         //for (caseID map loop)**
         allClosedTickets = true;
         for (Ticket__c ticket: scase) { // Ticket loop
           System.debug('checkcase---' +ticket);
             **// save LastModified date of the highest date**
             if (ticket.GLOBAL_Ticket_Status__c != 'closed') {
                 allClosedTickets = false;
                 //caseIDs.add(ticket.GLOBAL_Goal__c);   **// case ID of current Records.**
             }
         }
         if (allClosedTickets = true) { **// all closed so Case can be closed**
             // if lastModifiedDate greater than 7 days then
               **// add CaseId to casesToUpdate**
         }
       } 

           Integer totalTickets = CaseID_TicketList.get(caseID).size();
           Integer closedTickets = 0;
           for(Ticket__c ticket : CaseID_TicketList.get(caseID)){
               if(ticket.GLOBAL_Ticket_Status__c == 'Closed'){
                   closedTickets++;
               }
           }
           if(closedTickets == totalTickets) {
               casesToUpdate.add(new Case(Id = caseID, Status= 'Closed'));
           }
       }

       if(!casesToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
           update casesToUpdate;
       }
   }

      global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
      {
          **// Finishing the Batch Apex Class**
       }

   }
   ```

Can anyone help me out please.

Thanks

Comment: What's the relation to salesforce-communities ? Please try to only select tags specifically related to your questions. Do you mind removing that tag, or explaining why it should be there ?

Comment: Apologies for selecting the wrong tag  Samuel De Rycke. Thank you for the update.

Comment: What is the state of the current functionality.  Is it not accomplishing what you want?  What is it doing?  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: The state of currently functionality was that i was populating all the records of cases instead of specific records. so the changed the querylocator queue set to open ,breached and escalated so thats fine. i have left comments in the code which has gaps to make it work properly. if you can help me out in filing the gaps, will be much appreciated

Comment: You have a bug in your code: `if(allClosedTickets = true)` should be `if(allClosedTickets)`; the way you have it written will always evaluate to true, because you are assigning true to the value before checking the condition. `==` is used for comparison, `=` is for assignment. However, you shouldn't normally use `booleanValue == true` or `booleanValue == false`; simply say `booleanValue` or `!booleanValue`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply sfdcfox, this is my first try with Scheduled Batch Apex and so far i have only made to code whatever i could. i would appreciate if anyone could correct my code to match the requirements..

Comment: Another bug is in your SOQL query.  You are looking for Cases with 3 different Statuses at once.  Open And Escalated And Breached.  These should definitely be ORs as the case cannot have more than one status.

Comment: Can anyone please help me write the code.

Comment: @sfdcfox, just as an aside, there is a pretty "normal" use case to use "... == true/false" in Boolean comparisons in Apex; if it's possible the value can be null, just using a test like if "(!myNullValue)" will throw an "attempt to de-reference a  null object".

Comment: @jkraybill True, except (a) they clearly initialized the variable, and (b) unless you speak of outside data sources, one should never intentionally leave a boolean value null; this allows for logic bugs. For example, `if(someVal == true) { ... } if(someVal == false) { ... }` (OOPS! Neither branch got evaluated), or `if(someVal == false) { ... } else { ... }` (So null == true?). In practice, a null boolean value will almost always be a sign of a logic error, so one should avoid intentionally this feature. Unless, of course, you're like me and you *want* to confuse future maintainers...

Comment: Can anyone help me fill out the gaps and change the code where ever is necessary